# How to align algorithm2e with text outside?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e

I am having trouble aligning my algorithm with the text outside of it. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\oddsidemargin -0.25in
\textwidth 7.0in         
\topmargin 0.0in
\headheight 0.0in
\headsep 0.0in
\topskip 0.0in
\footskip 0.4in
\textheight 8.8in         

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %for including .jpeg files
\usepackage[algoruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amstext} % for \text macro
\usepackage{array}   % for \newcolumntype macro

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm
        \begin{figure}[h]
          \centering
          \begin{minipage}[h]{0.7\linewidth}
            \begin{algorithm}[H]
              \caption{\textsc{Some Algo}($I$)}
              \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
              \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
              \SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{1cm}
              \SetAlgoLined
              \DontPrintSemicolon
              \SetArgSty{textnormal}

              \Input{Some input description.}
              \Output{Some output description.} 

              \For{$i \leftarrow 1$ to $n$} {
                Do something \;
              }
            \end{algorithm}
          \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}

        Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm
        \begin{figure}[h]
          \centering
          \begin{minipage}[h]{0.9\linewidth}
            \begin{algorithm}[H]
              \caption{\textsc{Some Algo}($I$)}
              \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
              \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
              \SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{1cm}
              \SetAlgoLined
              \DontPrintSemicolon
              \SetArgSty{textnormal}

              \Input{Some input description.}
              \Output{Some output description.} 

              \For{$i \leftarrow 1$ to $n$} {
                Do something \;
              }
            \end{algorithm}
          \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following:
[image: Algorithm not aligned with text surrounding it]

In both cases, the text outside of the algorithm is not aligned horizontally (to the left) with the start of the algorithm. Could someone give me some advice about this?

Comment: Rather use [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set the page layout/geometry, instead of setting margin lengths manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Instead of placing the algorithm inside a float and requesting it to stay in-place, just use the `algorithm` environment with the `H`ere float specifier. If you want the algorithm to be narrower than the remainder of the text block, then you can wrap it inside a `minipage` (like you've already done).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[algoruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm

    \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{\textsc{Some Algo}($I$)}
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
        \SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{1cm}
        \SetAlgoLined
        \DontPrintSemicolon
        \SetArgSty{textnormal}

        \Input{Some input description.}
        \Output{Some output description.} 

        \For{$i \leftarrow 1$ to $n$} {
          Do something \;
        }
      \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}

    Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm Some text describing the algorithm

    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.9\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{\textsc{Some Algo}($I$)}
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
        \SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{1cm}
        \SetAlgoLined
        \DontPrintSemicolon
        \SetArgSty{textnormal}

        \Input{Some input description.}
        \Output{Some output description.} 

        \For{$i \leftarrow 1$ to $n$} {
          Do something \;
        }
      \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: I laughed at the diplomatic "You're doing it wrong.".

Comment: Thank you! i wrapped it all in a figure environment hoping it would help with alignment but it really didn't. Clearly, less is more